# Methods newly added in the subclass cannot be called when declared with interface

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I extended the ArrayList and trying to implement an enhanced ArrayList. So I added several functions to this subclass of ArrayList like so:

```
public class NiceList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public boolean someNewMethods() {

        // balh blah blah...
    }
}
```

Then I declare a new `NiceList` object using `List` interface type:

```
List<String> test = new NiceList<>();
```

But then I just found that these methods that I write for the NiceList cannot be called using the object `test` which just created:

```
test.someNewMethods(); // cannot resolve method someNewMethods()
```

Is this implies that: As long as you trying to use interface as the declarative type to make your program more generic, you can only use those methods that were defined (or asked to override) in that interface? Why is it? Can you guys provide me with any references? Is there any workaround to make my program more generic?

Thank you guys in advance here.

======================================

Appreciated! Now I think I really understand the concept of interface know.

Comment: Well... Does a `List` have a method called `someNewMethods`? nope, only a `NiceList` does have it. If you want your `List` to make use of this method and the additional funtioncalities declared in `NiceList` your `test` should be declared as `NiceList<String>`... Why is that? imagine you´d pass any type of `List` to a method, an `ArrayList` and a `NiceList` for example. how´d your `ArrayList` call `someNewMethod`?. By defining `test` as `List` you´re also implicity declaring that you only want to make use of the functionalities defined within `List` (if there is no typecasting).

Comment: Make your program as exactly as generic as needed. If you *need* to be more specific, perhaps because you need extra methods, declare variables and parameters that are more specific. If you don't, then be more abstract.

Comment: `Is this implies that: As long as you trying to use interface as the declarative type to make your program more generic, you can only use those methods that were defined (or asked to override) in that interface?` Yes. `Why is it?` Because it's the point of interface and superclasses. Making a program generic won't allow you to call specific methods without downcasting, because specific is not generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As long as you trying to use interface as the declarative type to make your program more generic, you can only use those methods that were defined in that interface?

Yes

> Why is it that way?

Because the compiler 'sees' only the *public API* of the declaration type and not of the runtime type. You have to cast the instance to the type defining the methods you want to access.

> Is there any workaround to make my program more generic?

As long as you want to use the type `List` the answer is **no**. If you are willingly to use a new type like `MyList<T> extends List<T>` you have to use `MyList` everywhere where you like to access your new method(s).

Answer (score 0):

The declaring type of a variable settles the methods you may call on this variable (without downcasting) at compilation time.

If you declare a `List` variable, you can invoke methods of `List`.
If you declare a `NiceList` variable,you can invoke methods of `NiceList`.

> Is there any workaround to make my program more generic?

It is broad but to stay the most compatible with the `java.util.List` interface you should declare and pass `List` objects in methods and classes where you don't need `NiceList` specificities and declare `NiceList` only when it is required.
You could also avoid leaking the `NiceList` type everywhere in the client code if it is not required.

But clearly, it may fast become tricky and hard to respect.
Introducing a wrapper class that doesn't inherit `ArrayList` but compose it should be better as you isolate the coupling with `ArrayList` in the wrapper and you don't need any longer to try to conform to the `java.util.List` interface .